Gradient involving kronecker product of a vector and a matrix multiplied by another vector
Let $f(W):=AWx$ where $A$ and $W$ are matrices, $x$ is a vector. The gradient with respect to $W$ is given as:
$$\nabla_Wf(W)=x^\top\otimes A$$
Now let $g(W):=y^\top AWx$, where $y$ is another vector. The gradient with respect to $W$ is given as:
$$\nabla_Wg(W)=A^\top yx^\top$$
Noting that $g(W)=y^\top f(W)$, I am not able to reconcile the gradients using the product rule. It seems to suggest that,
$$\nabla_Wg(W)=y^\top\cdot\nabla_Wf(W)= y^\top\cdot(x^\top\otimes A)$$
The first equation for $\nabla_Wg(W)$ is a matrix, the second is not. By definition, $y^\top\cdot(x^\top\otimes A)= A^\top yx^\top$ does not appear to be true since dimensions don't seem to match, so it is confusing. Can you help?

The connections between the various gradients are easiest to see using differentials
$$\eqalign{
\def\LR#1{\left(#1\right)}
\def\vc#1{\operatorname{vec}\LR{#1}}
\def\k{\otimes}
\def\p{\partial}   \def\grad#1#2{\frac{\p #1}{\p #2}}
g &= y:f \\
dg &= y:df \\
 &= y:\LR{x^T\k A}\vc{dW} \\
 &= \LR{x^T\k A}^Ty\,:\,\vc{dW} \\
 &= \LR{x\k A^T}y\,:\,\vc{dW} \\
 &= \vc{A^Tyx^T}\,:\,\vc{dW} \\
 &= \LR{A^Tyx^T}\,:\,dW \\
\grad gW\;\; &= \;A^Tyx^T \\
\vc{\grad gW} &= \grad g{\vc W} \;=\; \LR{x\k A^T}y \\\\
}$$
$^{**}\,$Colons denote the matrix inner product (aka Frobenius product).

I'm using the notation in the book "Matrix Differential Calculus with Applications in Statistics and Econometrics". Its version of the chain rule is as the following:

Let $S$ be a subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$, and assume that $f: S \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^m$ is differentiable at an interior point $c$ of $S$. Let T be a subset of $\mathbb{R}^m$ such that $f(x) \in T$ for all $x \in S$, and assume that $g: T \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^p$ is differentiable at an interior point
$b = f(c)$ of $T$. Then the composite function $h: S \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^p$ defined by $$ h(x) = g(f(x)) $$ is differentiable at $c$ and $Dh(c) = (Dg(b)) (Df(c))$

Now, back to your post. Let $h(x) = y^T x$, then its differential is $Dh(x) = y^T$. In your post, you are already compute the differential of $f$, that is,
$$
    Df(W) = x^T \otimes A
$$
Since $g = h \circ f(W)$, we have
$$
     Dg(W) = Dh(AWx) \cdot Df(W) = y^T (x^T \otimes A) = x^T \otimes (y^T A)
$$
Without using the chain rule, we compute the differential of $g$ as follows: Since
$$
   g(W) = y^T A W x = (y^T A)Wx
$$
we have
$$
    Dg(W) = x^T \otimes (y^T A)
$$
which agrees to when we are using the chain rule.

Thanks, using outer product relation $x^T\otimes (y^TA) = \operatorname{Vec}(A^Tyx^T)$, seems to imply that $Dg(W)$ should be a vector. Is it right?

@Phoenix Yes, in this case, $Dg(W)$ is a row vector

But the gradient of a vector with respect to a matrix should be a third order tensor, isn't it? I get the matrix result $Dg(W)=A^\top yx^\top$ on matrixcalculus.org, but now you have shown that it is indeed a row vector. So why do we have these conflicting notions and results?

@Phoenix The answer from the site above calculating $$ \dfrac{\partial g}{\partial W} $$ Here, the notation of differential $Dg$ in my answer is $$ Dg(W) = \dfrac{\partial g}{\partial (\text{vec }W)^T} $$ (assuming that $g$ is a scalar function) So, if you arrange the terms accordingly, you will obtain the same answer.
